# Controlling presentation time of a css banner in qualtrics using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, qualtrics

I'm conducting an experiment on distractions, and would appreciate some help in coding my survey.

Currently, I have a css banner that appears on the left of my qualtrics survey:

```
.banner 
{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top:250px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Via look and feel --> add custom css.

My question is how can I control the timing of the box? That is, I would like it to appear after 1 or 2 seconds, and then stay visible for only another 1 or 2 seconds. I'm new to this kind of programming so any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is no cross-browser compatible way to do this without using Javascript.

Comment: That's fine. Do you think you could explain to me how to do this using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above, older browsers prevent a pure-CSS solution from working. Here's an example of using Javascript to show an element (`#foo`) after 1 second and then hide it after another two seconds:

```
function toggleFoo() {
    var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

    if (foo.style.display === 'block') {
        foo.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        foo.style.display = 'block';
    }
};

var t1 = setTimeout(toggleFoo, 1000);
var t2 = setTimeout(toggleFoo, 3000);
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/_mtr/aw2LQ

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful. I think I have it figured out, but I just have one more trivial question. How do I give my banner an ID? Do I just insert it into the html header like <div class="banner" id="banner"><img src=... or do I need to do it a different way?

Comment: Got it working! Thank you! Out of curiosity, could you tell me if there's a way to make qualtrics randomly select an image from a pool of images and insert it into the banner? I'd like to use several pictures for distraction in my experiment.